# Можно ли в приложении ASP NET MVC вывести консоль?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, консоль

Можно ли,запустив приложение ASP NET MVC, вывести консоль, что б когда включается сервер с моим сайтом- на серверном ПК была открыта консоль.
И как туда выводить данные?

Comment: "на серверном ПК была открыта консоль" - на рабочем столе какого пользователя? которого нет?

Comment: @Igor Есть IIS сервер с моим сайтом и когда он включается-хочу, что б была консолька, и туда выводить типа- "Пользователь X подключился". Как и обычное консольное приложение. Я просто хочу код консольного приложения вставить в сервер. Но и что б быстро видеть данные-хочу консоль

Comment: "IIS сервер ... когда включается" - нет там места, где может появится консольное окно

Comment: @Igor а есть ли какой-то способ на серверном ПК отобразить консоль и связать с моим ASP.NET приложением?

Comment: @RakzinRoman создаете текстовый файл, в который пишите все нужные вам события сервера. Создаете консольное приложение, которое по изменению текстового файла отображает новые строки на консоль

Comment: @Trymount хочется именно консоль. Я хочу выводить количество пользователей онлайн в режиме реального времени, ну и дополнительные значения- например их имена. Файл не подходит

Comment: @RakzinRoman почему нельзя создать страницу только для вас со всей необходимой информацией?

Comment: @Trymount ну наверное так и сделаю. Просто я думал, есть способ подвязать консоль.

Comment: Пишите в системный журнал Windows – это самый правильный и централизованный подход под сервером на ОС Windows.

Comment: И ещё. Действительно, где вы будете создавать окно консоли? Во-первых, рабочий стол создаётся только для пользователей, вошедших через «Удалённый рабочий стол», причём для каждого из сеансов рабочий стол будет свой. Во-вторых, программы на сервере, по хорошему, должны быть написаны в виде служб, не имеющих собственного GUI. **Как вариант, можно организовать «консоль» в виде настольного приложения, подключающегося к серверу и взаимодействующего с ним в реальном времени через сеть.**

Comment: @Arhad да, я создам просто страницу для меня, в которой буду всё видеть, как предложил  Trymount

Comment: Служба не может вывести консоль, *приложение Windows* (не IIS) может вывести конслоль с помощью AllocConsole (kernel32.dll) или если это *консольное* приложение. На уровне *приложение win* вы можете вывести консоль, приложение поставить на автозагрузку входа, а сообщения отправлять *приложению*, например, через *named pipe*

Answer (score -1):

Нельзя. Т.е. стандартный вывод через `Console.Write()` работать не будет, но можно использовать `Response.Write()`, если он подойдет для ваших целей, конечно.

Еще можно использовать `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`, но работать это будет только в режиме дебаггинга.

Или, как совершенно верно заметили в комментариях, используйте логирование в журнал Windows или текстовый файл.